# Integration testing in spring non transactional by mocking database calls

Tags: integration-testing, spring-data-neo4j, transactional

My database calls are mocked and the actual methods that invokes DB are annotated with @Transactional. When I execute test cases, it internally tries to create the transaction and fails as no driver found. The database used is Neo4j and is not running while executing test cases.  How can I test transactional methods in a non-transactional way? I tried annotating the integration test method with   `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)`. but that makes no difference

Comment: Since the question is also tagged with integration-test, I assume that you are setting up a Spring context in the test, right? Where do you draw the (layer, architecture,...) line in your test when saying 'database calls' are mocked?

Comment: yes, spring context is initialized. `@MockBean` inside test class mocks the database classes.